# Aliasing a command with special parameters

Tags: shell, command-line, alias, function

I would like to have an alias for the following code:-

```
g++ *.cc -o * `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`;
```

but I want that when I enter the alias it should be followed by the file name `*.cc` and then the name of the compiled program `*`.

for example:

```
gtkmm simple.cc simple
```

should run

```
g++ simple.cc -o simple `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need isn't an alias, but a function. Aliases do not support parameters in the way you want to. It would end just appending the files, `gtkmm simple.cc simple` would end like:

```
g++ -o `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs` simple.cc simple
```

and that's not what you try to achieve. Instead a function allows you to:

```
function gtkmm () {
    g++ "$1" -o "$2" `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`
}
```

Here, $1 and $2 are the first and second arguments. $0 is the caller itself:

```
gtkmm simple.cc simple
$0    $1        $2
```

You can test the function using `echo`.

You can find more functionalities about functions in the [Bash online manual](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/complexfunct.html).

Comment: Works fine just as expected

Comment: Better yet, create a `Makefile` and run `make`...

Comment: @lcd047 for one shot commands to test stuff creating a Makefile can be overkill.

Comment: but as i do random coding and i ve got a lot of different files across directories I don't need a makefile cause i would create a lot of make files for stand alone cpp files